# PyQt4 libraries and installation on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, installation, pyqt

it has been a while now I'm surfing the net trying to find the way to sucessfully install PyQt4 on different Mac OS's and I can't figure it out.

Does anybody know if there is out there a package I could easily install without having to go through the compiling?

I'm developing sone Python tools with PyQt guis and the idea is to be able to make them work on multy pltaforms.

Any hit would be gratly apreciated,
Cheers,
Lozo

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).  It will bundle up a python script as a Mac OS .app bundle.  Inside of there, if configured correctly, will be the copies of the PyQt and Python modules needed to run the program.

For packaging for running on Windows, there's [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).  Likewise, if configured correctly, it will handle copying all of the libraries into the directory the .exe is made.

From this point on either Mac or Windows, you can create an installer program, .dmg, etc., to distribute and install PyQt applications onto these platforms without having to worry about the end user having to build their own copies of PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PyQt4 from [PyPM Index](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pyqt4/).

Answer (score 0):

Install libraries from [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x) and then use Homebrew to install pyqt (google is your friend). I suggest looking at [this site](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/) for a tutorial on Mac OS X Lion.